# XML Filter Expression for WFS with using interoperability Connection Extension in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers, wfs, data-interoperability

I need to work with an WFS layer in ArcGIS Desktop and I want to use an XML filter, but it doesn't work for me. I don't know if I am doing something wrong, or if the layer is faulty.

This is the WFS service:

https://inspire.skgeodesy.sk/eskn/rest/services/INSPIREWFS/kn_wfs_inspire/GeoDataServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

and this is my filter:
`<Filter><PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>label</PropertyName><Literal>2</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo></Filter>`

and it gives me this error:

> This data set appears to be invalid. Please verify that your settings or file contents are correct and try again.

When I try to use the layer without the XML filter, it gives me every time a different output (different polygons).

Comment: Which featuretype (layer) are you requesting `cp:CadastralParcel` or `cp:CadastralZoning`

Comment: Note that `cp:CadastralParcel` only has only 59 features, but none have a cp:label of value `2` ~ `https://inspire.skgeodesy.sk/eskn/rest/services/INSPIREWFS/kn_wfs_inspire/GeoDataServer/exts/InspireFeatureDownload/service?VERSION=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAMES=cp:CadastralParcel&NAMESPACES=xmlns(cp,http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/cp/4.0)&`